# Accessing CSV row when using a class

Tags: class, csv, processing

*Edited with advise from below. STill working on minisming the code more. *
I am attempting to shift to using classes in my code. I have this functioning in a larger piece of code and I'm attempting to recreate the stepping action now using a class.

```java
 if (i< table.getRowCount()) {
    row = table.getRow(i);
    k=row.getInt("y");
    x=row.getInt("x");
  }

  //draw white ellipse visual
  ellipse(x*diam, y, diam, diam);

  // step next circle up
  y+=Step;

  // -- if off the set upper limit of the line,
  // swing right 


  if (frameCount%(k/Step)==0) {
    x+=Step;

    y=starty;
    // increment row counter
    i=i+1;
  }
```

I am trying to troubleshoot why I am unable to step through variable i as the rows in the csv table.

I am expecting k to print out the data in column named "y" in the csv file. 
I am expecting i to print out a number incrementing by 1 each time variable y reaches the value of k.

From printing out my variables i,k,x

k is successfully getting the data from csv file column named "y"

x is successfully getting the data from csv file column named "x"

y is successfully incrementing

i is not incrementing

y is not registering it has reached k.

my thoughts right now are that actually variable k is a marker for y to stop incrementing but should perhaps not be part of the Dot parameters in the constructor.

```java
// An Array of Dot objects

Dot[] dots;
// A Table object
Table table;
float diam=10.0;
int i;

void setup() {  
  size(560, 420);
  loadData();
  background(0);
  // set the animation speed
  frameRate(10);
}

void draw() {
  // Display all dots
  for (Dot d : dots) {
    d.display();
    d.move();
  }

}

void loadData() {
  // Load CSV file into a Table object
  // "header" option indicates the file has a header row
  table = loadTable("data.csv", "header");

  // The size of the array of Dot objects is determined by the total number of rows in the CSV
  dots = new Dot[table.getRowCount()]; 

  // You can access iterate over all the rows in a table
  int rowCount = 0;
  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    // You can access the fields via their column name (or index)
    if (i< table.getRowCount()) {
      row = table.getRow(i);
      float x = row.getFloat("x");
      float k = row.getFloat("y");
      float d = row.getFloat("diameter");


      //String n = row.getString("name");
      // Make a fot object out of the data read
      dots[rowCount] = new Dot(i,k, x, d);

      rowCount++;
    }
  }

  //  check to see if at end of data
  if (i == table.getRowCount()) {
    i = 0;//if so, loop back to first row
  }
}

class Dot {
  float x =10.0;
  float y=10.0;
  float diam=10.0;
  float k;
  int step=10;
  int startx =10;
  int starty=10;

  float i=0;

  Dot(float i_,float k_, float x_,float diam_) {
    k=k_;
    x=x_;
    i=i_;
    diam=diam_;
  }




  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    // draw a circle
    ellipse(x*diam, y, diam, diam);
  }

  void move() {
    // move next circle to the right
    y+=step;

    // -- if off the right edge of the line,
    // swing down and all the way to the left
    if (frameCount%(k/step)==0) {
      x+=step;
      y=starty;
      // increment row counter
      i=i+1;
    }

    // if off the bottom of the page, stop
    if (x>=width) {
      fill(0);
      text("done", width/2, height/2);
      noLoop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve] with just a few lines of code? Have you tried [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code to see exactly which line behaves differently from what you expected? Why are you creating two `Dot` instances for each row? The second `Dot` is overwriting the first one, so why bother creating it?

Comment: apologies. edited

Comment: I'm not trying to be annoying, but that's still not a [mcve]. We need to be able to copy-paste your program to run it ourselves. That means you need to isolate your problem to as few lines as possible, but those lines should still be a complete program.

Comment: Hello, sorry I went away to do exactly that-further my code to be minimal. Sorry for the delay in updating this post. In doing so I realised I was over complicating things and shifted to using a txt file keeping the code more streamlined and in an area I understood more. I will come back to trying to resolve the CSV issue and post here when I do. Thanks for trying to help me.